# Distribution of $|\sin(\Theta)|$ if $\Theta$ is uniform on $(0,2\pi)$ and arcsine distribution

Tags: probability, proof-verification, probability-distributions

Suppose $\Theta \sim Unif(0,2\pi)$ and $s \in (0,1)$. I am trying to find $P(\mid \sin(\theta) \mid < \sqrt s)$.

**My attempt:**

We have that

$$P(\mid \sin(\theta) \mid < \sqrt s) = P(-\sqrt s < \sin(\theta) < \sqrt s) = \\
= P(\sin(\theta) < \sqrt s) - P(\sin(\theta) < - \sqrt s) = \\ =P(\theta < \arcsin(\sqrt s)) - P(\theta < \arcsin(-\sqrt s)) = \\
= \frac{\arcsin(\sqrt s)}{2\pi} - \frac{\arcsin(-\sqrt s)}{2\pi} = \frac{\arcsin(\sqrt s)}{\pi}$$

where I've used the oddity of the arcsine function.

However, taking the derivative with respect to $s$ of this laxt expression yields

$$\frac{d}{ds}\frac{\arcsin(\sqrt s)}{\pi} = \frac{1}{\pi\sqrt{ s(1-s)}}ds$$

which integrates to $\frac{1}{2}$. Where did I miss a $2$ along the way?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89070/discussion-on-question-by-easymode44-distribution-of-sin-theta-if-theta).

Comment: (Comment reposted) Why omit every reference to the question which prompted this one?

Comment: (Comment reposted) You should review the definition of the arcsine...

Comment: You have all the answers in the chat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $x\in [0,1]$,
$$
\mathsf{P}(\sin(\theta)\le -x)=\mathsf{P}(\sin(\theta)\ge x)=\mathsf{P}(\arcsin(x)\le \theta\le \pi-\arcsin(x)).
$$
Thus,
$$
\mathsf{P}(|\sin(\theta)|\le x)=1-2\mathsf{P}(\arcsin(x)\le \theta\le \pi-\arcsin(x))=\frac{2\arcsin(x)}{\pi}.
$$

Comment: thank you for your answer, I appreciate the input.